# Is the fiberwise suspension of a Serre fibration a Serre fibration?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fibration

Let $\pi\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a Serre fibration.  Define $\Sigma_f\pi \colon \Sigma_f X \rightarrow Y$ be the fiberwise unreduced suspension of $\pi$.  Thus $\Sigma_f X = X \times [0,1] / {\sim}$, where $\sim$ identifies $(x,0)$ with $(x',0)$ whenever $\pi(x) = \pi(x')$ and also $(x,1)$ with $(x',1)$ whenever $\pi(x) = \pi(x')$.

**Question**: Must $\Sigma_f\pi \colon \Sigma_f X \rightarrow Y$ also be a Serre fibration?

I think this is probably false for Hurewicz fibrations, and I would also be interested in counterexamples in that more general context.

Comment: I believe that fiberwise reduced suspension does not preserve Serre fibrations. But I believe that fiberwise reduced suspension might preserve them. To see that this is the case it would be enough to see that fiberwise unreduced cone preserves Serre fibrations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lemma 6 in Section 3 of

*Vandembroucq, Lucile*, [**Fibrewise suspension and Lusternik-Schnirelmann category**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-9383(02)00007-1), Topology 41, No. 6, 1239-1258 (2002). [ZBL1009.55002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1009.55002).

(also available at https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82041491.pdf) seems to show that the fibrewise suspension of a Hurewicz fibration is a Hurewicz fibration. The proof uses lifting functions.

Answer (score 4):

"In any attempt to solve those two problems, one runs into a third one that
concerns a basic foundational problem in ex-space theory. Model theoretical considerations lead to the use of Serre fibrations as projections, or to the even weaker
class of qf-fibrations. However, only Hurewicz fibrations are considered in most of
the literature. There is good reason for that. **Fiberwise** **smash products,** **suspensions**, cofibers, function spaces, and other fundamental constructions in ex-space
theory do not preserve Serre fibrations."

From the introduction to Chapter 8 of "Parametrized Homotopy Theory" by May-Sigurdsson. I could not find a specific counter example stated.